# How to insert line breaks in views global custom text field?

Tags: views

My view renders plaint text output - no HTML allowed. I want to format my fields with `\n` line breaks. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With HTML not allowed, you don't allow line breaks.  You would need a `<br />` element to render a line break, otherwise it will be one big paragraph

If you have it set up the way you want, and all you want to do is add the `/n` to the output of a field:

- Add a Global Custom Text field (make sure it is below the field you want to add the /n to).
- Insert the token under Replacement Patterns for the applicable field.
- In the text box, add the `/n` after the token.

Comment: I want the output to have `\n` (text) line breaks.

Comment: in html, that is represented by <br /> tag.  There is no literal /n in html

Comment: But I'm not concerned with HTML; I am using the view's results for a plain text application. Do views fields only output HTML? I guess my question should be "can views output plain text?" Like this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/475722

Comment: Views is part of Drupal, which outputs HTML for website viewing - I have no idea how you would get Views to output plain text without any html, it wasn't designed to do that, it was designed for websites. Even modules like Feeds and similar use XML output, not text - you might have to write something custom

Comment: I made an edit to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could just run the text through nl2br();
Then your line breaks should convert to HTML ones.

`echo nl2br($val);`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php